# Netezza Emulator's status is not 'Online' and SPU VM is not running

Tags: vmware, netezza

I've installed'IBM PureData System for Analytics Software Emulator', a Netezza Emulator, and upon starting it gets the Host VM into a 'running' state after a while, however, the emulator's status is not 'Online' and the SPU VM is not starting. The log message shows:

...
...
Host: VMWare tools started
**Host: waiting for network stack startup timed out.**
Host Started.

Starting SPU. Checking SPU VM configuration... Applying SPU VM parameter changes...   vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "33" :prev: "32" tools.remindInstall = "FALSE" :prev: "TRUE"
**PowerOn problem: error: the operation was cancelled.

SPU was not started properly**

The text in bold is the cause of concern.

If you know a fix to these errors that will let the status become 'Online' and SPU VM run, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We have found the app that controls the order to not be consistent. So my suggestion is to add both VM's to your vmware so that you can change and control them. After you do this start the host and wait until it is fully running so you can login. After that start the SPU host. You can check on status by issuing a nzstate command on a regular basis. To determine if nzstate is running. After that run nzsql and you can function as if you  were on a regular Netezza db server.